# "No se pudieron habilitar las restricciones. Una o varias filas contienen valores que infringen las restricciones NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY.' "

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Tengo un error que me tiene estancado  en un proyecto.
Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos que me permite obtener datos de dos tablas:

detalle_venta :

```
TABLE [dbo].[detalle_venta](
    [idddetalle_venta] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idventa] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idproducto] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cantidad] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [precio_unitario] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_detalle_venta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

venta:

```
TABLE [dbo].[venta](
    [idventa] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idcliente] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fecha_venta] [date] NOT NULL,
    [tipo_documento] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [num_documento] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ventas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

el procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
 procedure [dbo].[ver_ventas]
as
SELECT T.idventa,T.idcliente,T.fecha_venta,T.tipo_documento,T.num_documento,I.idproducto,I.cantidad,I.precio_unitario 
 from dbo.detalle_venta  as I join dbo.venta as T
on I.idventa = T.idventa
```

este es el resultado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta el momento todo bien, sin embargo 
he creado un form (formulario) en Visual Studio que me permita mostrar los datos alojados por el procedimiento de almacenado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui el error

[image: error]

espero ayuda, por favor y gracias!

Comment: La solución es poner la propiedad EnforceConstaints del dataSet en false.

Answer (score -2):

En mi caso, es muy extraño, pero a pesar del retor, retorno el dataset que sí que se crea, y tiene los datos. Muy extraño, pero sigo investigando la causa.
Con un try cath controlo el error y aunque informo al usuario, no lo tomo como un error catastrófico. Pero me deja muy mosca.

Unos minutos despues:
Localizado: El problema es mi tabla de SQL LITE está definida con 100 CHARS, pero de alguna manera, desde mi aplicación ANDROID, hacen un insert con mas caracteres.
Estos caracteres SÍ que entran en la tabla, a pesar de la limitación, y no da error.
Pero al abrirlos desde otra apliación en .NET da error, como es lógico. Dato definido 100, pero intenta leer mas caracteres.

RESUMIENDO.
Por algún motivo, los datos que lees en el dataset, no son los que esperabas, en tamaño o en alguna otra restricción.

Comment: Estás seguro que estás respondiendo a la pregunta? Esa es sobre sql server y VB.NET. Tú hablas de Android y SQLite